# Check if an AWS S3 Bucket exists else create it

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3

I am trying to use a Jenkinsfile to create an Amazon S3 Bucket for a project, however I want to first check if the bucket exists, else create the bucket with the parameter given.

I am implementing this in the **Create Bucket** stage of the Jenkinsfile using this command:

```
script {
  if ("aws s3api bucket-exists --bucket ${params.BUCKET}") { // Check if the bucket exists
     echo 'Bucket already exists'
  } 
  else ("aws s3api create-bucket --bucket ${params.BUCKET} --region ${params.REGION} --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=${params.REGION}") { // Create the bucket if it does not exist
     echo 'Bucket created'
  }
}
```

**Here's my Jenkinsfile**:

```
pipeline {  
  agent any
  parameters {
    string(name: 'BUCKET', defaultValue: 's3-pipeline', description: 'Amazon S3 Bucket Name')
    string(name: 'PREFIX', defaultValue: 'my-website', description: 'Amazon S3 Bucket Application Directory')
    string(name: 'REGION', defaultValue: 'eu-west-1', description: 'Amazon S3 Bucket Region')
    string(name: 'BUILD', defaultValue: 'public/', description: 'Application Build Directory')
    string(name: 'INDEX', defaultValue: 'index.html', description: 'Application Index File')
  }  
  stages {  
    stage('Build project') {  
      steps {
        echo 'Running build project phase'
        sh 'npm install' // Install packages
        sh 'npm run clean' // Clean project 
        sh 'npm run build' // Build project 
        sh 'ls' // List project files
      }  
    //}
    stage('Create Bucket') {  
      steps {  
        echo 'Running create bucket phase'
        withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', credentialsId: 'AWSCredentials', secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']]) { 
          script {
            if ("aws s3api bucket-exists --bucket ${params.BUCKET}") { // Check if the bucket exists
              echo 'Bucket already exists'
            } 
            else ("aws s3api create-bucket --bucket ${params.BUCKET} --region ${params.REGION} --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=${params.REGION}") { // Create the bucket if it does not exist
              echo 'Bucket created'
            }
          }
        }  
      }   
    }  
    stage('Deploy') {  
      steps {  
        echo 'Running deploy phase'
        withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', credentialsId: 'AWSCredentials', secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']]) { 
          sh 'aws s3 ls' // List AWS S3 buckets
          sh "aws s3 sync ${params.BUILD} s3://${params.BUCKET}/${params.PREFIX} --delete" // Sync project files with AWS S3 Bucket project path
        }  
      }   
    }
  }
  post { 
    success {  
      echo "Deployment to Amazon S3 suceeded for JOB - ${env.JOB_NAME} with BUILD NUMBER - ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
      echo "The Jenkins BUILD URL of this project is: ${env.BUILD_URL}" 
      echo "The Amazon S3 BUILD URL of this project is: https://${params.BUCKET}.s3-${params.REGION}.amazonaws.com/${params.PREFIX}/${params.INDEX}" 
      // mail to: team@example.com, subject: "Deployment to Amazon S3 suceeded for JOB - ${env.JOB_NAME} with BUILD NUMBER - ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
    }  
    failure {  
      echo "Deployment to Amazon S3 failed for JOB - ${env.JOB_NAME} with BUILD NUMBER - ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
      echo "The Jenkins BUILD URL of this project is: ${env.BUILD_URL}"
      // mail to: team@example.com, subject: "Deployment to Amazon S3 failed for JOB - ${env.JOB_NAME} with BUILD NUMBER - ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
    }  
  }  
}
```

However, it was returning to me that the bucket already exists, even though it's not there.

How to check to see if the bucket exists and then make as a decision based on a return value to create the bucket if it does not exist.

The [AWS S3 CLI bucket-exists](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/wait/bucket-exists.html?highlight=bucket%20exists) method documentation does not see to provide that for me, rather they just have this:

> Wait until 200 response is received when polling with head-bucket. It
> will poll every 5 seconds until a successful state has been reached.
> This will exit with a return code of 255 after 20 failed checks.

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code is Groovy code :

```
script {
  if ("aws s3api head-bucket --bucket ${params.BUCKET}") { // Check if the bucket exists
     echo 'Bucket already exists'
  } 
  else ("aws s3api create-bucket --bucket ${params.BUCKET} --region ${params.REGION} --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=${params.REGION}") { // Create the bucket if it does not exist
     echo 'Bucket created'
  }
}
```

In Groovy, the condition `if ("some random string") { ... }` will always be evaluated to `true`, unless the given string is evaluated as *falsy* (see [Groovy documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#Groovy-Truth) for more details).

And more importantly, the given command is not executed! It's just a string evaluated to `true`.

If you want to execute a shell command in a Jenkins pipeline, you need to use the step [`sh`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script), which is NOT what you're doing here.

You could try this :

```
script {
  def status = sh(script: "aws s3api head-bucket --bucket ${params.BUCKET}", returnStatus: true)
  if (status == 0) {
    echo 'Bucket already exists'
  } else {
    echo 'Bucket created'
  }
}
```

Or, more specifically :

```
script {
  def status = sh(script: "aws s3api head-bucket --bucket ${params.BUCKET}", returnStatus: true)
  if (status != 0) {
    sh "aws s3api create-bucket --bucket ${params.BUCKET} --region ${params.REGION} --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=${params.REGION}"
  }
}
```

To implement try and catch, you could do this:

```
stage('Create Bucket') {  
  steps {  
    echo 'Running create bucket phase'
    withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', credentialsId: 'AWSCredentials', secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']]) { 
      script {
        def status = sh(script: "aws s3api head-bucket --bucket ${params.BUCKET}", returnStatus: true)
        def create = sh(script: "aws s3api create-bucket --bucket ${params.BUCKET} --region ${params.REGION} --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=${params.REGION}", returnStatus: true)
        try {
          if (status == 0) { // Check if the bucket exists
            echo 'Bucket already exists'
          } 
          else create() {  // Create the bucket if it does not exist
            echo 'Bucket created'
          }
        } catch (err) {
          echo "Caught: ${err}"
          currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
        }
      }
    }  
  }   
}
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks for this. Let me try it out now.

Comment: Can you add how I can call a method to create the bucket if it does not exist. I did this but it is not working:  `def create = sh(script: "aws s3api create-bucket --bucket ${params.BUCKET} --region ${params.REGION} --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=${params.REGION}", returnStatus: true)`. and then called the create method `else (create) { // Create the bucket if it does not exist`. But it is throwing an error.

Comment: `else (create)` is not a valid syntax. Do you mean `else { create() }`? Just start with an `echo`, just like in your question, and see if it works.

Comment: I edited my answer to be more specific to your use case.

Comment: I just marked the answer as correct as it worked for me. Thank you. I noticed that `aws s3api bucket-exists` does not exist again in the AWS S3 CLI API doc, it throws an error, saying `method not found`, so I had to use `aws s3api head-bucket` to check the existence of the bucket.

Comment: But I have an issue when the bucket does not exist, the command `aws s3api head-bucket --bucket ${params.BUCKET}"` throws an error `An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadBucket operation: Not Found` and aborts the operation. Meanwhile the command `aws s3api create-bucket --bucket ${params.BUCKET} --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=${params.REGION}` still evaluates and creates the bucket. I will have to run it again to get a successful operation. How can I handle the exception so that it does not break the build when a bucket does not exist. Can you add it to your answer?

Comment: I have been able to implement it. I have modified the answer to include it.